# Recode column values in unix

Tags: linux, shell

```
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 1 1 2
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 1 1 2
1859116 2255037 21608 Yes 06S14028969 11 0 2 3
1859117 2268746 34027 Yes 06S14028970 10 0 2 1
```

Above is the example of my data set. I want to replace the values of 7th column in a way that 1 should be replaced by 2 and 0 should be replaced by 1. So the outcome i am expecting should be like following.

```
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 2 1 2
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 2 1 2
1859116 2255037 21608 Yes 06S14028969 11 1 2 3
1859117 2268746 34027 Yes 06S14028970 10 1 2 1
```

I have tried using this approach

```
awk 'NR==1{$10="Pheno";print;next}\
 $7 == "1" {$10="2"};\
 $7 == "0" {$10="1"}1'  old.txt |column -t > new.txt
```

and then removing the first row and extracting columns of interest. But i need straight forward way.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `$10` instead of `$7`? You need `1` after the `$7 == "1"` block.

Comment: Couldn't you just write `$7++` to add 1 to whatever is in the 7th column?

Comment: @Barmar with pre-increment you wouldn't even need the `1`: `awk '++$7'`

Answer (score 1):

This could be simply done by putting a simple condition to check if `NF`(number of fields in each line) is greater OR equal to 7 then increment 7th field with 1 and print edited/non-edited line then(by doing this we can avoid adding 1 if number of fields are lesser than 7 in any line).

```
awk 'NF>=7{$7+=1} 1' Input_file
```